# Cochran Mantel Haenszel vs. Breslow-Day - what's the relationship?

Tags: categorical-data, contingency-tables, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I was told, that the Breslow-Day tests the assumption on homogeneity for the CMH, the same way we check homogeneity of variances in ANOVA (to focus only on the means, not being "confounded" by the different variances).

The CMH seems to calculate the common odds ratio adjusted for some categorical strata (it's the weighted mean of all per-stratum odds ratios, right?), and the Breslow-Day - calculates the equality of odds ratios across the strata. OK.

But then I read that the CMH doesn't need this and the Breslow should never be used for validating the CMH. What's the truth?
Are they replaceable? It seems they test something very similar!

Comment: As an aside, I view these methods as dated and prefer to formulate models that encompass them and use maximum likelihood (and likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ tests) or Bayesian estimation.  That way you can handle continuous covariates, longitudinal data, and much more.

Comment: Yes, I think, I could use the ordinal logistic regression or the log-linear one instead, which would allow me to use covariates. But I'm required to use exactly the tests and thus I need some help regarding the CMH and B-D. It's not something I can choose.

Comment: What do yo mean "required"?  Obsolete methods should not be required.

Comment: This is what my professor asks to do and we all have to use these methods in this very assignment. There is no choice. I appreciate what you say and you clearly see that I am aware of alternatives. But I am really searching for a help to complete my assignment in THIS very topic.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than learning a lot of special cases, it is better to learn unified models that not only cover the special cases but also allow several extensions, including multilevel modeling, longitudinal data, and allowing for continuous covariate. Maximum likelihood and Bayesian estimation are your friends.  Special emphasis should be given to semiparametric models.  And with models it is more clear what assumptions you are actually making.  The CMH technique should be considered obsolete.